# Неверное поведение модификатора i в awk

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, debian, awk

Доброе утро. Есть проблема, решение которой я не вижу, а вернее оно слишком громоздкое.

Есть скрипт:

```
ls -f "./$var" | grep -iE "(jpe?g|png|bmp)$" | wc -l
ls -f "./$var" | grep "JPG" | wc -l
ls -f "./$var" | grep -i "jpg" | wc -l

ls -f "./$var" | awk '
    BEGIN {count_photo=0;} {
        if ($0 ~ /(jpe?g|png|bmp)$/i) {
            count_photo++
        }
    }
    END {printf "%s\n" count_photo}'
```

Вывод:

```
790
790
790
232
```

Как вы поняли, в директории `$var` лежат фотографии, которые нужно посчитать. Пожалуйста, не спрашивайте почему `awk`, это лишь малая часть всей выборки и она не работает как надо, а через `grep` выходит дольше.

Если условие `awk` поправить на `($0 ~ /(jpe?g|png|bmp|JPG)$/i)`, т.е. добавить `JPG`, то показывает: `387`. Больше, но всё равно не то.

Если убрать модификатор `i`, который отвечает за регистр: `($0 ~ /(jpe?g|png|bmp|JPG)$/)`, то подсчёт верный, но, как вы понимаете, теряется гибкость, т.е. для расширение типа `jPg`, нужно прописывать в условие.

Названия фотографий вида:

```
1000-ice.JPG
1047-ice.JPG
1094-ice.JPG
1141-ice.JPG
...
```

Система:

```
# uname -a
Linux rr-photo 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

# awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Comment: для начала, модификаторов на подобии `/i` в синтаксисе регулярных выражений awk нет... это не перловка... а вот почему он не вызывает ошибку синтаксиса и что именно проверяет это условие я понятия не имею...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в `man` нет, согласен, но где-то я это подсмотрел, а где уже не помню =/

Comment: можешь поверить, в `awk` модификаторов регэкспов никогда не было (по крайней мере в POSIX/BSD/GNU вариантах)... они есть для команды `s` в `ed`/`sed`/`vi` и в перле...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать `tolower($0)`, чтобы осуществлять проверку на соответствие шаблону строку в нижнем регистре. Кроме того, чтобы проверять только расширения, необходимо искать и точку перед самими расширением, то есть надо добавить `\.`: `/\.(jpe?g|png|bmp)$/`.

```
awk 'BEGIN {count_photo=0;} {
      if (tolower($0) ~ /\.(jpe?g|png|bmp)$/) {
        count_photo++
      }
    }
    END {printf "%s\n",count_photo}'
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/YAbevF).

**Регистронезависимость в `awk`**

Флага `i` в `awk` не существует. В [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk//manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) написано, что `tolower($1) ~ /foo/` — один из возможных способов регистронезависимого поиска, который будет работать в любой POSIX-версии `awk`.

Ещё один вариант, который тоже всегда работает, использовать "скобочные выражения" (bracket expressions), `[aA]`. `[aA]` найдёт как `a`, так и `A`. Это громоздко и неудобно, зато более гибко.

В **`awk` версии GNU** существует переменная `IGNORECASE`. Значение `1` (и любое другое, отличное от нуля) включает регистронезависимость, `0` выключает её. Все следующие за этой переменной операции с регулярными выражениями и строками регистронезависимы:

```
awk 'BEGIN {count_photo=0;} {
        IGNORECASE = 1
        if ($0 ~ /\.(jpe?g|png|bmp)$/) {
            count_photo++
        }
    }
    END {printf "%s\n",count_photo}' file > newfile
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, спасибо, ответ засчитаю чуть позже. По поводу модификатора `i`, нет идей почему так, а не иначе? Этому скрипту уже порядка полугода и раньше такого бага за ним не было замечено.

Comment: На странице [mawk(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mawk) о нём ни слова.

Comment: Я б исходники поискал/посмотрел, если уж так интересно по поводу i.

Comment: @tum_ Я добавил ещё 2 способа.